# Can I use a spline model with higher p-values?

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, splines

This is my spline model which *does* satisfy proportional hazards. I created this due to being advised against categorizing my variable.

I arrived at the variables (without splines) by "backward" stepwise reduction which I heard makes the p-values not valid. Can I still use this spline model despite having some p-values slightly inflated over alpha=0.05 (hypertension & anaemia)? They weren't inflated prior to the spline.

```
age                                   8.60e-08 ***
anaemia1                              0.069564 .  
creatinine_phosphokinase              0.023973 *  
ns(ejection_fraction, knots = c(15))1 9.27e-10 ***
ns(ejection_fraction, knots = c(15))2 0.228695    
serum_creatinine                      0.000307 ***
hypertensionPresent                   0.101466
```

Comment: What is your goal? If your goal is prediction, inflated p-values are not an issue. Instead you should beware of overfitting, which can be tested on a separate test set.

Comment: My goal *is* prediction thank you. What other goals could I have had? Descriptive? Genuine question. What steps would I take had I had a different goal?

Comment: Examples for other goals: Find the direction of the effect a particular predictor and whether this effect is due to chance or systematic, or learn something about variable importance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two somewhat separate issues here.

First, if this model had been developed without looking at the data, it would seem to be completely acceptable for your stated purpose of prediction, *provided it was not overfit*. That's what @cdalitz says in a comment. An apparent violation of proportional hazards with respect to `ejection_fraction` was fixed by modeling it flexibly with a spline. Good.

To answer your question in that respect, there is no requirement that each individual regression coefficient estimate be "significantly" different from a value of 0, particularly at an arbitrary threshold of *p* < 0.05, in a model. What you want is for the model as a whole to represent your data in a way that is likely to carry over to new data from the same population. The nominally "non-significant" predictors can be adding to the information provided by the others. See Chapter 4 of Frank Harrell's [course notes](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf), in particular Section 4.12.1 for a summary of how to develop a predictive model.

Second, your model *is at risk of being overfit* because of your choice to use backward selection. That's the point that @DemetriPananos makes in another answer (+1). A model fit by backward selection isn't necessarily the "correct" model in terms of the actual associations of the predictors with outcome. It just happens to be one that seems to fit *your current data* the "best." If it's overfit you won't be able to predict new cases reliably, even if you seem to have the "best" model for the current data set. That doesn't necessarily rule out some limited backward selection; even Harrell's notes in Section 4.12.1 say, after 12 *earlier* steps in model building:

> Do limited backwards step-down variable selection if parsimony is more important that accuracy. But confidence limits, etc., must account for variable selection (e.g., bootstrap).

If parsimony is that important, do your backward selection with tools that account properly for your use of the data to refine the model. Harrell's [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) provides such tools with its `validate()` function. But don't use backward selection as a starting point for building the model; follow his advice on the prior 12 steps, drawing on your understanding of the subject matter.

Answer (score 2):

> stepwise reduction [sic] which I heard makes the p-values not valid. [...] Can I still use this spline model despite having some p-values slightly inflated over alpha=0.05 (hypertension & anaemia)?

I mean...you could, you're just running a risk of non-generalizability.

Stepwise selection is known to select the "correct" model with low confidence, even when modelling assumptions are consistent with the data generating process.  If you use a model obtained from stepwise selection, that is fine, you just have to be ok with [these 11 problems](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/stepwise-regression-problems/) amongst others.

Comment: The correct model's `ejection_fraction` didn't satisfy proportional hazards. Should I simply proceed without that assumption being met for that variable?

Comment: What exactly is "the correct model" and how do you know it?  If you know the "correct" model, why do an inference to begin with? Note here "the correct model" is the model which generated the data. Its unlikely you know that (and even more unlikely such a thing exists since models are convenient fictions).

Comment: I assumed you meant that the correct model is the model step() returns. For the Schoenfeld's test, I get a p-value of 0.024-- indicating that the variable doesn't satisfy proportional hazards which is why I used the spline.